# Change Main Window name WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

i was wondering how to change the name displayed in the window so it can show whatever i want instead of just MainWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Window.Title property.

Comment: Thanks, i just noticed there was the title property, it was pretty obvious but im still starting, thanks again for helping.